# how to adjust Autororation in iOS 6?

Tags: ios6

Size inspector menu has changed in iOS 6.
How to get the same work done as we are doing it in iOS 5?
I have drawn 4 buttons on screen

UL      UR

L       R

LL      LR

My aim is to even if i rotate my screen orientation position of button should not be displaced.

Comment: Please use the auto layout in ios6